# Ajax.BeginForm seems to redirect Action completion

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am currently developing a .net mvc 3 application.  Here is the problem.  For some reason, Though I am using Ajax.BeginForm and the right action is getting called, after the action completes, it is trying to redirect as if to another page that does not exist.  However, I want it to stay on the same page just submit the form using ajax and return some friendly message to the user after the action completes.

Here is my Ajax.BeginForm page:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post" }))
{
    <div id="lnkContainer"><a href="#" onclick="javascript:document.forms[0].submit(); return false;">Update</a>&nbsp;</div>
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message, new { style = "width:575px" })
}
```

Here is my Action:

```
[Authorize]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public PartialViewResult Action(ActionModel actionModel)
{
database-related code
.....
database-related code

return PartialView(); 
}
```

Comment: Just a hunch based on a past experience: have you added and included the "unobtrusive Ajax" JS files?

Comment: Generally, this is caused by missing scripts. Without them, the forms are just normal forms and will post back as expected of them.

Comment: <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.debug.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: I think I have them all added

Comment: Also, I thought that Ajax.BeginForm would negate redirection.

Comment: Why are you using a link to submit the form? Have you tried using a submit button instead of the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain your problem lies in `onclick="javascript:document.forms[0].submit();"`. This will submit the form as a normal POST request. If you want to use the `@Ajax.BeginForm` helper, use a regular `<input type="submit">` to trigger the submit. If you really need to use a link, then using `@Ajax.BeginForm` really doesn't matter because you will have to code submitting an Ajax request using jQuery, etc.

As far as `Ajax.BeginForm` and redirection is concerned, the form will revert to a normal HTML form in the event that the user has disabled javascript in their browser, or if your missing the appropriate scripts, etc.

Comment: So, would I have to make the link simulate the button click?

Comment: @user1790300 Yes, if you decide not to use an `<input type="submit">` button, then you would have to write jQuery code to submit an ajax POST when the user clicks on the link.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, I solved it by adding the below code in the **BundleConfig.cs**
`bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryajax").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"));`

and then the below code in **_Layout.cshtml**

`@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryajax")`